# Scipy.optimize.mininize get number of function evaluations

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I would like to store the number of function evaluations (Fevals) made by a Scipy optimization algorithm in an external variable to count the final number of evaluations made by the entire program (Scipy is repeated many times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it out from the optimization object and add the value at every outer Scipy call. In order to see how to get the number of function evaluations please see [this scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult). You can refer to the examples on the same page to inspect an example.

In case this does not help, you may wrap your cost function and try something like this:

```
class F(object):

    def __init__(self, fn):

        self.n_calls = 0
        self.fn = fn

    def __call__(self, x):

        self.n_calls += 1
        return self.fn(x)

return F(fn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`callback`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) argument to pass a function that will increment a global integer.